# disableAutoPan not working with Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I am using the Maps API (v3, javascript) to display a bunch of local properties for sale on this client's website. When the user mouses over a marker, it loads an infoWindow with property information. Problem is, when this is down near the edge of the map, it pans the map to show the info window, which can cause issues when lots of markers are close by.

So I added disableAutoPan: true to the infoWindow call, and it seems to solve the problem. However, after some more testing, if the user manually moves the map and then hovers over a marker, the resulting infoWindow pans the map. It's like it's ignoring the setting for the infoWindow.

Anyone else have this issue or any ideas how to solve it? The code I used to call the infoWindow is below:

```
infoWindowAjax = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  disableAutoPan: true,
  maxWidth: '260'
});
```

Comment: Interesting.  Can you load your code to JS Fiddle or link to your implementation?